# Push messages to AWS active mw from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amq

The use case is to create a microservice-http-endpoint AWS lambda function which publishes message to Amazon ActiveMQ, I tried searching for the same but could not find an answer, is it possible to publish messages to AMQ from AWS lambda functions?

Google Search

NA

NA

Comment: Have a look to this doc, it can maybe help yourself: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/invoking-aws-lambda-from-amazon-mq/

Comment: This is the opposite case, this describes to pull messages from queue using lambda functions.

Comment: You will have to include the required active mq library in your package(depending on what language you use for lambda). Just make sure lambda is the part of same VPC as AMQ is and appropriate security groups.